# Telegram bot - sendMessage() returns Promise object, but should be Message object

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

On success of sendMessage() method, the sent Message object is returned, but I'm getting Promise object instead. Source: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

**What should i do to get Message object?**

```
console.log(bot.sendMessage(chatId, `some text`))
```

Log result is below

```
<ref *1> Promise [Object] {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined,
  _cancellationParent: <ref *2> Promise [Object] {
    _bitField: 1,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: [Function (anonymous)],
    _promise0: [Circular *1],
    _receiver0: undefined,
    _cancellationParent: Promise [Object] {
      _bitField: 1,
      _fulfillmentHandler0: [Function (anonymous)],
      _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
      _promise0: [Circular *2],
      _receiver0: undefined,
      _onCancelField: [Function (anonymous)],
      _branchesRemainingToCancel: 1
    },
    _branchesRemainingToCancel: 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should await an async function by adding await in the beginning of your function call like this:

```js
console.log(await bot.sendMessage(chatId, `some text`))
```